# Globally Hiding Attributes From Array Or JSON Conversion in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Sometimes you may wish to limit the attributes that are included in your model's array or JSON form, such as passwords. To do so, add a hidden property definition to your model:

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $hidden = ['password'];

}
```

This is model specific.

Is there any method to hide globally?

ie,I want to hide deleted_at and created_by from all model `json` result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is by creating a base model. Like this:

```
class BaseModel extends Model {
    protected $hidden = ['deleted_at', 'created_by'];
}
```

And then all your models extend from that:

```
class User extends BaseModel {

}
```

---

Note that this way if you wanted to add some hidden fields for a specific model you would have to as well specify those two global hidden attributes:

```
class User extends BaseModel {
    protected $hidden = ['deleted_at', 'created_by', 'password'];
}
```

If that bothers you, you could merge the global attributes in from the contructor:

```
class BaseModel extends Model {
    private $globalHidden = ['deleted_at', 'created_by'];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array()){
        $this->hidden = array_merge($this->globalHidden, $this->hidden);
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. happy to see again you :)